# ReactJS variable change occurs in multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, reactjs

Sorry about the confusing title, I really didn't know what the categorize this as. I was having an issue regarding changing a variable that was set to an Array element. I have since figured out a way to accomplish what I wanted, but this was still bugging me so I figured I'd ask here.

```
playCard(event){

    let tempArray = this.state.playerDeck;
    let playArray = this.state.playerDefaultCards;

    playArray.push(tempArray[event.target.id]);
    console.log(playArray[1].image);  //logs image data

    let tempObject = tempArray[event.target.id];
    tempObject.image = "Test";
    console.log(playArray[1].image); //logs "Test"
    tempArray[event.target.id] = tempObject;

    this.setState ({playerDeck: tempArray, playerDefaultCards: playArray});
    console.log(this.state.playerDefaultCards[1].image); //Also logs "Test"
  }
```

Basically I have 2 arrays of objects with image sources. When an image is clicked on, I wanted it to go from the playerDeck to the playerDefaultCards, and then I just wanted to change the image source in the playerDeck to a blank string.

I thought that if I made a temporary variable and set it equal to the array element, changed that temporary variables image property and then set the array element equal to that new object everything would work out.

However when I change tempObject.image = "Test" it changes in both the tempArray and the playArray, which to my knowledge shouldn't happen. This is the source of my confusion.

Obviously I'm missing something but so far I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Even though you set `tempArray` equal to `this.state.playerDeck` you are not making a copy of this variable. When you push items into `tempArray` you are still mutating `this.state.playerDeck`. If you want to make copies of these arrays you'd need to do something like `let tempArray = this.state.playerDeck.slice();` ... although I can't say I'd recommend doing this with React state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`playArray.push(tempArray[event.target.id])` copies the reference at `tempArray[event.target.id]` to the object rather than the object itself.

You can use `Object.assign` to create a new object for the `card` you want to move, then you can edit the original.

You should also `.slice()` the state arrays to make sure you do not change them outside of `setState`.

Something like this:

```
playCard(event){

    const tempArray = this.state.playerDeck.slice();
    const playArray = this.state.playerDefaultCards.slice();

    const selectedCard = Object.assign({}, tempArray[event.target.id]);

    playArray.push(selectedCard);
    tempArray[event.target.id].image = "Test";

    this.setState({playerDeck: tempArray, playerDefaultCards: playArray}); 
}
```

One thing to watch out for is `setState` is fast, but it is not instant. A `console.log` called right after `this.setState` will possibly execute before the update is completed and return the old value. `this.setState` can take a callback function if you need to do something as soon as it finishes.

`Object.assign` is not supported by all browsers, so you may need a polyfill for it.

[Object.assign documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: Thanks for the help, object.assign() was the way to go. I was unaware that objects were passed by reference until now.